# Converting a class library to a webapp in Visual Basic?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I was delivered several hundred source files for a web app original written in classic ASP, but somewhat ported to VisualBasic.NET and ASP.NET

It didn't come with any form of project or solution files.

I'm trying to get it setup to build, but am struggling. If I try to open it as a WebSite (ala Web Site instead of Web Project), I get hundreds of errors, mostly from missing references...

So, I tried creating a new class library project and added all the files, less errors now, but still hundreds.

Is there a way to tell VB to convert this class library project to a Web project? I think that may resolve a lot of the errors.

I'm a C# guy, and I haven't worked in VB since VB6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new ASP.NET Web Application Project in Visual Studio, delete the default files that are created, then add all the existing files to the project. This seems like the easiest way to get started that I would try first.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to migrate a web project to a web application project, there's still bunches of articles around from 2005, maybe there are some tips that can apply for your situation:

http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/Migration2/Migration2.aspx